# Solve $\sum_i e^{-\frac{a_i}{2\tau ^2}}=M$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Does the following equation have a closed form?

$\sum_i^{i=n} \exp{(-a_i/2\tau ^2)}=M$

where $\tau,M, a_i, i=1,\cdots,n>0$, and the $a_i$s are arbitrary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The $a_i$s are arbitrary?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra,Hi, thank you. I re-edit it.

Comment: @AlecS, Yes, they are.